# Как конвертировать JSON в swift 3

Tags: json, cocoa, swift3

Не могу найти как сделать json читабельного вида. Допустим есть {"x":5,"b":6} хотелось бы чтобы получилось

```
{  
"x":5
},
{  
"b":6
}
```

Ключи заранее не известны

Делаю так

```
func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Приходит:

```
["x": 5, "b": 6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо сначала строку перевести в json

```
func convertToDict(text:String) -> [String:Any]? {
if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
do{
    return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, option: []) as? [String:Any]
}catch{
    print(error.localizedDescription)
   }
 }
 return nil
}
```

А уже потом в в данный вид

```
func JSONStringify(value: AnyObject, prettyPrinted: Bool = false) -> String {
if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(value) {

    do{
        let data = try JSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(value, options: options)
        if let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
            return string as String
        }
    }catch {

        print("error")

    }

}
return ""
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает